# TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, rtk-query

I am trying to trigger a rtk query end point from a function

```
const [getcitycode, { isLoading, error, data, isSuccess, isError }] = useLocationQuery();

const getLocationDetails = async () => {
  const queryItems = { latitude: lat, longitude: long };
  await getcitycode(queryItems);
};
```

this is the end point

```
location:builder.query({
  query: (queryItems) => {
    console.log('qitems', queryItems);
    return {
      url: `https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?
        at=${queryItems.latitude},${queryItems.longitude}&lang=en-
       US&apiKey=apikey`,
      method: 'GET',
    };
  },
});
```

the api is working fine , i cross checked by hard coding latitude and longitude value and getting successful response.

response from api

```
{
  "currentData": {
    "items": [[Object]]
  },
  "data": {
    "items": [[Object]]
  },
  "endpointName": "location",
  "fulfilledTimeStamp": 1675000730551,
  "isError": false,
  "isFetching": false,
  "isLoading": false,
  "isSuccess": true,
  "isUninitialized": false,
  "refetch": [Function refetch],
  "requestId": "uKRzgDyIYxgdDc1wAcScf",
  "startedTimeStamp": 1675000730127,
  "status": "fulfilled"
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get this error?

Comment: await getcitycode(queryItems). const[getcitycode, 
{isLoading,error,data,isSuccess,isError}]=useLocationQuery();

Comment: What is `useLocationQuery`?

Comment: it's a hook created by rtk query

Comment: Are you sure that it returns an array? I don't see any example with an array as you try to do

Comment: the problem occurring when i am trying to destructure the response

Comment: you can see the response in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251477/discussion-between-raghuram-and-konrad).

Comment: I think `useLocationQuery` returns an object and not an array, try: `const { isLoading, error, data, isSuccess, isError } = useLocationQuery();`

Comment: const { isLoading, error, data, isSuccess, isError } = useLocationQuery(); writing like this works perfectly but i have to trigger the api when a function runs that''s why i added getcitycode    await getcitycode(queryItems);
i also want to send data in the request as queryitems

Answer (score -1):

Change from (replace square brackets with curly brackets):

```
const [getcitycode, { isLoading, error, data, isSuccess, isError }] = useLocationQuery();
```

```
const {getcitycode, { isLoading, error, data, isSuccess, isError }} = useLocationQuery();
```

Comment: That's certainly a syntax error.